# Чтение из COM-порта в переменную в командной строке Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, bat, com-port, serialport

Всем привет!

Хочу принимать и обрабатывать данные от Ардуино в bat-скрипте. Данные представляют собой строку, заканчивающуюся \r\n. Посылаются каждые 5 секунд. Есть ли способ поместить их в переменную в этом же скрипте без промежуточного файла?

Пробую такой код:

```
@ ECHO OFF
MODE COM5 BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8 > nul
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`TYPE COM5`) DO set x=%%i
ECHO Data=%x%
```

и ничего не происходит, команда `FOR` просто бесконечно ждет данные от команды `TYPE COM5`.

Пробовал также:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`TYPE COM5 ^> CON`) DO set x=%%i
```

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`COPY COM5 CON`) DO set x=%%i
```

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`TYPE COM5 ^> CON ^| FIND /V "notmydata"`) DO set x=%%i
```

Данные отображаются на экране, но скрипт как бы крутится внутри команды `TYPE`, и переход к `DO` не происходит.

Перерыл весь интернет, все советуют Powershell, который прекрасно с задачей справляется. Но ради спортивного интереса и расширения кругозора хочется сделать именно на чистом  CMD и без временных файлов.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш цикл будет крутиться бесконечно, поскольку COM5 как файл никогда не закончится.
Попробуйте читать построчно

```
@echo off
MODE COM5 BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8 > nul
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`TYPE COM5`) DO (
 ECHO Data=%%i
 goto break
)
:break
```

Проблема останется с тем, что если из порта читать нечего, батник будет висеть и ждать данные

Comment: Не работает.
Дело в том, что  `TYPE COM5` никогда не заканчивается, и переход к блоку `DO` не происходит.

Comment: Я даже пробовал модифицировать данные, чтоб после каждой строки шел символ завершения файла (ASCII №26). Это работает, если TYPE COM5 стоит отдельной строкой в скрипте. Но если TYPE cтоит внутри оператора FOR, то этот символ перестает интерпретироваться как конец файла и просто выводится на экран как "→".
В общем, надо или как-то заставить TYPE завершиться внутри оператора FOR, или найти другой способ чтения из COM5.

Comment: действительно. тогда копайте в сторону type ...|more для more как-то можно было ограничить количество строк

Comment: Внезапно выяснилось, что работает `SORT<COM5`. Позже выложу полное описание в ответ к своему вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

Удалось добиться помещения данных из COM-порта в переменную при  небольшом изменении пакета данных от Ардуино.

Если пакет заканчивается не на `\r\n`, а  на `(char)26` — символом конца файла, то для чтения из COM-порта можно использовать команду `SORT`.

```
@ ECHO OFF
MODE COM5 BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8 > nul
ECHO Listening port
:start
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`SORT^<COM5`) DO ( set x=%%i)
ECHO x=%x%
timeout /t 1 /nobreak
goto start
```